# "Gradle files have changed since last project sync." message always shows up

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm working on an Android Studio project of which I write while constantly move back and forth from laptop to desktop using usb stick. There has been no problem for couple of months I tried this since Android Studio went stable, until today this message keeps showing up no matter how many times I sync the gradle:

> Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync may be necessary for the IDE to work properly.

Gradle Console indicates that the build is successful. I also tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, even reinstalling Android Studio, still the message pops out.

What seems to be the problem? Is it not recommended to write a project on multiple Android Studios?

Here's a look of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.simplifyinc.prodigy"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "0.3.2"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.oguzdev:CircularFloatingActionMenu:1.0.2'
    compile 'net.the4thdimension:audio-wife:1.0.3'
    compile project('libraries:android-crop')
}
```

Comment: I don't think you would have an issue as long you do not keep shuffling generated files. I know it sounds stupid. but could you check that once?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea which files or folders on project folder are allowed to be deleted and manually.. I always assume cleaning project would take care of that generated files thing

Comment: yes that is a problem. so either you should delete all the build files. or when you are copying them, just remove all the files and folders mentioned in the `.gitignore` folder

Comment: just tried that, still no luck..

Comment: that actually works after I delete the folder .idea, thanks man! put it as answer and I'll check that. really appreciate it.

Comment: but I am surprised, because I am very sure that the `.gitignore` file mentions the .idea folder too

Comment: it does mention the folder libraries and file workspace.xml in .idea folder, .gitignore does not specify to delete the whole folder, which I did, frustratedly.

Comment: Oh ok, well that's a new trick I learned today. thanks a lot!

Comment: for windows maybe this answer help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46351634/7611966

Answer (score 6, accepted):

each IDE(even if it is the same build number)  uses its own metadata. an example would be the location of the Android sdk.when shuffling files between different systems, you would have to make sure that none of the system generated files are copied.
the safest way would be to delete the all the files and folders mentioned in the `. gitignore` file. 
and as in this particular case, the `.idea` folder.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to restart the AS using the "Restart and invalidate cache" option.

Answer (score 27):

in build.gradle(module:app) 
change 
build tool,( in my case its 23.0.1)
targetSdkVersion (23) and 
in dependency 
compile version
("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0") 
to latest 
This happens due to gradle updates

*****Check your PC date*****

Comment: You are right! It's the wrong date/time causing it.

Comment: @ALi0007 How to solve this date problem? My PC date was wrong. After I fixed that, this problem appears

Comment: Problem solved. I changed Date Modified attribute for all files inside my project.

Answer (score 14):

You must check your PC or laptop date and time. Correct your date and time will resolve your issue.

Comment: helpful for me..  :)

Comment: Wow you saved my time

Answer (score 1):

The modified date for some of my files were set to a future date/time (still havent figured out the cause). Updating the modified time of each file in the project using `touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm ./*` and then the same for those with a `.` prefix `touch -mt YYYYMMDDhhmm ./.*` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

this error had happened to me when I changed my computer time carelessly
configer my computer time,and reset the time,this error solved

Answer (score 0):

this error happen when android studio 2.3.3 available and i ignore it, upgrade your android studio to 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

For Me Below Steps Worked:

1) Delete .idea folder

2) Delete build folder

3) opened each file mentioned in .ignore with notepad and add a space , remove a space and saved file again. this will not effects the file but the trick is notepad changes the Date modified attribute of file.

[image]