# Gradle files have changed since last project sync. A project sync may be necessary for the IDE to work properly

Tags: android

I am just learning android programming , when I try to learn to make the project relating to the MySQL database , I get an error as shown.
Can help me how to solve the error
[image: Android Studio]

Comment: Try pushing the "Sync Now" button! Don't worry, it won't explode.

Comment: that I have tried , but it still can not

Comment: It still shows the message on top? Two things you can try: 1. Rebuild the project (Build -> Rebuild Project). 2. On your screen, I see gradle build finished with two errors. You might want to see what that is and tell us. Click on "Gradle Console" on the lower right hand corner and look for red text.

Comment: ok I will give a picture of his errors

Answer (score 6):

The cause of the problem is that your system date is incorrect. Update your PC date and time.  Then invalidate and restart the IDE. The error message should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

Solve this problem by going to(Windows) "date and time setting" --> "internet time" --> "change setting" --> "check synchronize with an internet time server" --> "update now"

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error. You will see this banner when you change `build.gradle` inside of Android Studio. There is a "Sync Now" link on the end of the banner that you can click to sync the files. Or, click on Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files from the main menu.

Comment: Even i'm facing problem, even after trying sync now immediately this banner re appears.Help!!